# 99% of my Geometry class can’t solve this problem. I’m in the 99%

Tags: geometry

I need help with this geometry problem, number 22.
[image: Problem 22]

I’m in Chapter 3, so we should not be using Pythogerean or Trig just yet. I’m not allowed to use anything past congruent triangles and closely related theorems, as this is a culmulative review in a popular textbook.

Comment: The identity $$ AD^2 = \frac{2\,AB^2+2\,AC^2-BC^2}{4}$$ can be proved in many ways, but without exploiting the Pythagorean theorem... argh...

Comment: hint: area of ACD is equal to area of ADB

Comment: This problem is wrong. x must be greater than 40, or else AC has negative length. AD is shown as x-10 and must be shorter than AB, which is sqrt(x). The problem is, x-10 > sqrt(x) for all x > 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is wrong. Looking at AC, x must be greater than 40, or else the segment has non-positive length. AD is shown as x-10 and must be shorter than AB, which is shown as sqrt(x). The problem is, x-10 > sqrt(x) for all x > 40. There is no x that satisfies this problem.

I wonder how 1% of your class managed to solve it?

Comment: There was a solution of x=100 floating around, which as you can easily tell, is incorrect. I guess the textbook company had made a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Pythagorean theorem:  (I know that you say you shouldn't need it, but)

$(\frac {x}{10}-4)^2 + (0.08x)^2 = x\\
0.0164 x^2 - 1.8x + 16 = 0\\
x = 100$

$AC = \frac {100}{10}-4 = 6\\
BC = 0.08\cdot 100 = 8\\
AB = \sqrt {100} = 10$

But, this is inconsistent with the statement $AD = x-10 = 90$

Comment: AC is equal to AD?

Comment: Typos in the answer, I think: 0.164 should be 0.0164, and AD = x - 10. But agreed, the problem has no solution. (The other root is x = 400/41, but that can be ruled out because it makes AC < 0.)

Comment: @MichaelBehrend  Thanks...